# count of product with parent_category_id

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables 
table 1: cat_a

[image]

table 2:prod_a

[image]

Out put must be

```
When category_id =1 then product_id count must be 7 
when category_id = 3 then product_id count must be 5
when category_id = 6 then product_id count must be 3
when category_id = 7 then product_id count must be 2
when category_id = 5 then product_id count must be 2
```

Please help me . I have searched lot of questions and answers and forums. couldn't find exact solutions. 
I don't want  spoon feeding answers . Please mention the hint or way with answer.

Answer (score 0):

My problem resloved.

```
SELECT count( product_id)
FROM prod_A 
WHERE  category_id IN (SELECT category_id FROM cat_A  START WITH category_id = <i_category_id>
     CONNECT BY PRIOR category_id = parent_catogory);
```